# How to Manage In-Memory Cache Values

Tags: c#, caching, in-memory-cache

I'm working on something related to in-memory cache using the built-in libraries in .NET, such as AddMemoryCache and AddDistributedMemoryCache. However, I have a question in mind. Is there an interface where I can view, see the details of the data I put into the cache, and manually delete them if necessary? For example, is there a tool like RedisInsight for this? This is my first question here, sorry for my novice level.

I did some research, but couldn't find a tool specifically for that.

Comment: Do you mean like a Monitoring or inspection tool? Why would you need that?

Comment: You say in-memory cache, and you mention RedisInsight; are you using redis? or are you using something like the [asp].net in-process cache (`AddMemoryCache`, `AddDistributedMemoryCache` etc)? the "what features are available?" question will depend heavily on *exactly* what is driving the cache

Comment: @Fildor yes i mean something like that. Actually i dont need but it feels me safe to control what i am working at

Comment: @MarcGravell i forgot to mention but i mean the asp.net built in features AddMemoryCache, AddDistributedMemoryCache as you sad

Answer (score 0):

As of .NET 8 there isn't any built-in way to view the items in a C# IMemoryCache. The interface doesn't expose any methods or properties that would do what you seem to be asking for.

I have done something similar to provide a read-only view of the data in the cache by keeping a list of the cache keys and exposing an API endpoint that returns the value of each of those keys, but only temporarily and for troubleshooting purposes, and not modifying any of the values. You could also theoretically expose an endpoint that would clear all the items in the cache. But it would depend on your application's specific needs, and given the overhead I wouldn't pursue it if you don't have a real-life justification for this.